# Find x in a^x = a (mod n)

Tags: math, equation, numerical-methods, modular-arithmetic

I want to calculate **a<sup>m</sup> mod n**, where **n** is a prime number, and **m** is very large. Rather doing this with binary power calculation, I'd like to find such **x** that **a<sup>x</sup> = a (mod n)** and then calculate **a<sup>(m mod x)</sup> mod n**.

Obviously such **x** exists for any **a**, because powers mod n loop at some point, but I didn't find out how to calculate it with modular arithmetics. I wonder if I missed something or maybe there exists some numerical method for that?

Comment: `^` is power ? made `<sup>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your modulus is prime, that makes it easy to get a start, as by Fermat's (inappropriately dubbed "little") theorem, then

```
a^n ≡ a (mod n)
```

for all `a`. Equivalent is the formulation

```
a^(n-1) ≡ 1 (mod n),  if n doesn't divide a.
```

Then you have

```
a^m ≡ 0 (mod n) if a ≡ 0 (mod n) and m > 0
```

and

```
a^m ≡ a^(m % (n-1)) (mod n) otherwise
```

(note that your suggested `a^(m % x)` is in general not correct, if `m = q*x + r`, you'd have

```
a^m ≡ (a^x)^q * a^r ≡ a^q * a^r ≡ a^(q+r) (mod n)
```

and you'd need to repeat that reduction for `q+r` until you obtain an exponent smaller than `x`).

If you are really interested in the smallest `x > 1` such that `a^x ≡ a (mod n)`, again the case of `a ≡ 0 (mod n)` is trivial [`x = 2`], and for the other cases, let `y = min { k > 0 : a^k ≡ 1 (mod n) }`, then the desired `x = y+1`, and, since the units in the ring `Z/(n)` form a (cyclic) group of order `n-1`, we know that `y` is a divisor of `n-1`.

If you have the factorisation of `n-1`, the divisors and hence candidates for `y` are easily found and checked, so it isn't too much work to find `y` then - but it usually is still **far** more work than computing `a^r (mod n)` for one single `0 <= r < n-1`.

Finding the factorisation of `n-1` can be trivial (e.g. for Fermat primes), but it can also be very hard. In addition to the fact that finding the exact period of `a` modulo `n` is usually far more work than just computing `a^r (mod n)` for some `0 <= r < n-1`, that makes it very doubtful whether it's worth even attempting to reduce the exponent further.

Generally, when the modulus is not a prime, the case when `gcd(a,n) = 1` is analogous, with `n-1` replaced by `λ(n)` [where `λ` is the Carmichael function, which yields the smallest exponent of the group of units of `Z/(n)`; for primes `n`, we have `λ(n) = n-1`].